# Cassandra Cluster - Production (Vwmare)

Tags: linux, cassandra, vmware, san

I intend to create a cassandra cluster with 10 nodes (16v cpu + 32 Gb of RAM each).

However, for the generation of this cluster, I intend to use a high-end storage (SSD only) with 320k IOPS. These machines will be spread over 10 machines with VMWARE 6.7 installed. Any contraindications in this case? Even though it is a very performative architecture for any type of application / database?

Comment: also look to VSAN settings/setup - for DataStax there are some settings around VSAN replications, etc. You can read about it at https://www.datastax.com/press-release/datastax-announces-datastax-enterprise-production-support-vmware-vsan

Answer (score 0):

It looks server side is quite okay but you need to consider other things like network, OS and data modelling part to opt good performance in Cassandra. 
You can take a look datastax recommendation here :-
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html

Comment: Has anyone used or uses a similar solution? Is there a performance problem? Yes, I think, in following the tips sent in this link, but with VMware and storage as stated.

Notice, that I will use VMWARE with STORAGE, not VSAN. - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html